# text file limitation in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, matlab, text

I am trying to read a wav file into an array and then write it on a text file using android application. To validate that the values on the text file are correct, I compare it with Matlab.
 I used the same code in Android and Java, and in both cases the results are different, by different I mean that Android saves only 5946 readings out of 20000 readings. On the other hand, when I run the Java code, I get the full 20000 readings !

I have no idea why I get 5946 readings when I run the Android application, while I get 20000 readings when I run the java code. Is there any limitation on the text file size?

Following is the code I wrote (plz note that I use a library for wav file reading):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /////////////////////

        Done = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Done.setText("processing");
        double[] buffer;
        int len;



        ///Reading the wav file into buffer/////

        filePath = "mnt/sdcard";
        File filein = new File(filePath, "audio.wav");

         try
          {
             // Open the wav file specified as the first argument
             WavFile wavFile = WavFile.openWavFile(filein);

             // Display information about the wav file
             wavFile.display();

             // Get the number of audio channels in the wav file
             int numChannels = wavFile.getNumChannels();

             // Create a buffer of 100 frames
             buffer = new double[20000 * numChannels];

             int framesRead;
             double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
             double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;

             do
             {
                // Read frames into buffer
                framesRead = wavFile.readFrames(buffer, 20000);

                // Loop through frames and look for minimum and maximum value
                for (int s=0 ; s<framesRead * numChannels ; s++)
                {
                   if (buffer[s] > max) max = buffer[s];
                   if (buffer[s] < min) min = buffer[s];
                }
                len=buffer.length;
             }
             while (framesRead != 0);

             // Close the wavFile
             wavFile.close();

             // Output the minimum and maximum value
             System.out.printf("Min: %f, Max: %f\n", min, max);


//////////////Saving the array (buffer) into a text file (before.txt)////////

             filePath = "mnt/sdcard";
             for (int i=0; i<20000; i++)
             {

                   if(fout==null)
                        try {
                          fout=new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath,"before.txt")));
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                      String str=Double.toString(buffer[i])+" " ;
                      //Log.v(str,Double.toString(i));
                      try {

                        fout.writeBytes(str);

                      } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }

             }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
             System.err.println(e);
          }



        if(fout!=null)
        {
            try {
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        Done.setText("Done");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the size of the text file on the smartphone is around 300 KB, However, when I browse it from the PC it is 100KB !
It seems that the system keeps the same size every time I write on it !
Reboot of the phone solved the issue. (Android MTP support does not show recent files until the device is rebooted).
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282